# How to make draoppable not accept items with a specific class

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I can set an `accept` attribute in my droppable element as shown below:

```
item.droppable({ accept : '.class'})
```

Now, elements matching  `.class` can be dropped into the droppable and rest not.

But I need to reverse this: set a class to the items that should not be dragged, and the over event shouldn't trigger for the items having particular class.

Is any way to do it?

Comment: Add more details to the question.

Comment: provide code what you have done so far...!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector as shown below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
  $('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: ':not(.invalid)',
    over: function() {
      console.log('called only for valid item')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
div.invalid {
  background: silver;
}
div.droppable {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class=" draggable"></div>
<div class=" draggable invalid"></div>
<div class="droppable"></div>
```

Elements with class `invalid` are not draggable, and doesn't trigger the over callback as well.